# Button Change Background Color on Click / Press

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have what I thought would be an easy issue to resolve but for the life of me I cant get exactly what i want using WPF (coming from a WinForms background).

All I am trying to do is create a button which the background color changes just while the button is pressed / clicked.  Once the button is released, it reverts back to normal.  Based on this I am trying to also have nothing happen on Mouse Hover.

Ive managed to create a template to remove the Mouse Over effects but can seem to figure out how to change the background color just whilst clicked / pressed and then reset.

I have been working off this template from another Stack Over flow post which gives me a nice transition of the button being pressed.

I am happy to lose the effect but was using this as a basis for trying to understand how to piece it all together.

```
 <Style x:Key="InformButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10px"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.2"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.85"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Padding="4,2" 
                    BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                    CornerRadius="3" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="contentShadow"
                        Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}" >
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="content" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                           <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.0" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#007DB8" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple - you already have a "Is Pressed" trigger - you just need to add a background setter there, for example:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
```

To make it simple to understand, we can see a simplified version of your template:

```
<Style x:Key="InformButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue">
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4,2"
                        BorderBrush="DarkGray"  CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="content" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here you can see that all we have is a basic background (Light blue), a content presenter for the content and a trigger that if the button is pressed, will change the color to red.

Personally, I think that this minimal template also looks better as it will match the global font settings and style.

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as expected.  What if I wanted to override / change the border of the button on press event only?

Comment: Similarly. First you should find the property on the Button that you want to change, in this case `BorderBrush`. Then you need to add to the trigger a setter for this property, e.g. `<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>`.

This will not work immediately - because the template is not using this property from the button. To fix this you need to add a setter to the style itself (like the background): `<Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>` and instead of hard coding to the border in the template, use a TemplateBinding: `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`.

Comment: I would suggest you to read more about templating in WPF, it is not difficult and very powerful.